# Can we edit EDI files in Arcesb?

Tags: edi

I have an EDI file which i want to edit. Currently what i'm doing is using arcesb i convert it into xml and then edit it and again convert it into edi format and then send the file.
Does Arcesb provide such functionality which can edit the files on the fly?  If not then can you suggest me some other tools which provide such editing functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about ArcESB, but you can edit and validate X12 files using edi.stedi.com/inspector.

Answer (score 0):

EDI files are simple text files, and you can use every text editor, such as Notepad or Notepad++ to edit EDI files.

Comment: I'm aware of that but i need to use some API or something that gives me the transformed file after editing. Need to do it through code not manually.

Comment: You could try [EdiNation](https://www.edination.com/) - it has both visual EDI files analyzer/JSON converter and REST API so you can automate the transformation. BTW, I work for EdiNation.